# Loop counter visability in function call

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I was working on a `javascript` project when ran into an interesting predicament where the counter in my `for` loop is visible in a function called inside said`for` loop. Here is an example:

```
function callback(){
  console.log("My value is " + i);
}

function setup(){
  for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    callback();
  }
}

setup();
```

The output of this program is:

```
My value is 0
My value is 1
My value is 2
```

This is an issue in cases where I use the variable `i` in a `for` loop that calls a function who uses `i` in its own `for` loop. I know I can just use a different variable in the callback function, but I don't believe this will be practical in all cases.

I am running this code in Firefox 42.0

Thank you.

Comment: Always use local variables as loop counters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `i` is a **global** variable. You have declared it outside of these two functions, and it can be accessed in both of them.

Always use local variables as loop counters:

```
function setup(){
  for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    callback();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of not defining your variable, which result in an automatic definition/usage in global scope. This is invalid and will throw an exception in Strict Mode, and should be considered a bug and always be avoided.

This behavior is not limited to `for` or any other usage.

The correct usage is to always define your variables in the relevant scope:

```js
'use strict'
function callback(){
  var i;
  console.log("My value is " + i); // i is undefined
}

function setup(){
  var i;
  for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    callback();
  }
}

setup();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this is typical programmers misunderstanding about the scope of a variable.

In your case since the variable is not declared , `javascript engine` adds it to global scope and hence its accessible outside your for loop as well.

you can fix this problem by declaring a local scope variable inside the for loop,so that its visibility is not exposed outside the `for` loop scope.

**JS CODE:**

```
function callback(){
 console.log("My value is " + i);
}

function setup(){
  for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    callback();
  }
}

setup();
```

*Note:This typically happens with every developer, thats why i would suggest you to use strict mode in your javascript code, `'use strict'`(this will throw errors for all those silent errors which was getting ignored earlier by JavaScript engine)*

[More info about Strict Mode @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)